# How to install VS Code extensions in a Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, dockerfile, vscode-extensions, vscode-remote

Is there a way to install VS Code extensions in a `Dockerfile`?

Answer (score 6):

If your goal is not to repeat the installation of the VS code extensions, my suggestion is to mount $HOME/.vscode-server/.

For example, in a docker-compose.yml

```
services:
    your_container:
        ...
        volumes:
            - ./volume/vscode-server:$HOME/.vscode-server
```

Or in `docker run`

```
docker run -it -v ./volume/vscode-server:$HOME/.vscode-server your_image bash
```

Then, install the required extensions inside the container. The next time you set up the container, there will be no need to reinstall extensions.

Comment: Doesn't work fully for me. Extensions are installed, but eg. cpptool can't start: `cpptools client: couldn't create connection to server.... failed. .../cpptools EACCES`. If mounted it doesn't seem, to be able to fix the file permissions. Doing it all the time by hand would be a bit tedious.

Answer (score 5):

Apparently, while most browser-based VS Code forks (including `openvscode-server`) do not permit headless installation of VS Code extensions (as seen from my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74419906/9962007)), it is possible to do such automated installs using `docker build` in one of them: **Code Server ([code-server](https://github.com/coder/code-server))**, like in this sample `Dockerfile`:

```bash
FROM ubuntu:22.04

RUN apt update && apt install -y curl

# install VS Code (code-server)
RUN curl -fsSL https://code-server.dev/install.sh | sh

# install VS Code extensions
RUN code-server --install-extension redhat.vscode-yaml \
                --install-extension ms-python.python
```

---

For longer extensions lists the installation can be performed sequentially using a simple loop:

```bash
RUN EXT_LIST="redhat.vscode-yaml ms-python.python" && \
    for EXT in $EXT_LIST; do code-server --install-extension $EXT; done
```

Relevant part of the `docker build` log:

```
[..]
 ---> Running in 59eea050a2db
[2022-11-13T10:13:58.762Z] info  Wrote default config file to ~/.config/code-server/config.yaml
Installing extensions...
Installing extension 'redhat.vscode-yaml'...
Installing extension 'ms-python.python'...
Extension 'redhat.vscode-yaml' v1.10.1 was successfully installed.
Extension 'ms-python.python' v2022.16.1 was successfully installed.
[..]
```

Comment: To get the identifier in vscode, remote connect to the container, install the extension you want.  In Entensions find the installed extension, click on the cog, select Copy Extension ID.  It will be now in your clipboard and you can paste it into your Dockerfile.

Comment: @Marc, a word of caution: code-server cannot use all extensions from the official 
Visual Studio Marketplace due to legal restrictions imposed by MSFT, so it uses an open-source extensions repo (Open-VSX Extension Registry
at https://open-vsx.org/), which may lack some extensions that you are looking for, but those that are open-sourced there, should have extension names just as in the VS Marketplace

Answer (score 0):

Per the [VS Code Documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/devcontainerjson-reference#_vs-code-specific-properties), the extensions property is specific to VS Code and can only be configured using .devcontainer.

The best you can do is if the extension has a CLI, you can install that. For example,

```
RUN npm install prettier -D --save-exact
```

Then use npx:

```
npx prettier --check .
```

Answer (score 0):

This is sadly disallowed by design, as confirmed by this error message you will see in your `docker build` log when you attempt to run `code --install-extension` or `openvscode-server --install-extension`:

```
Command is only available in WSL or inside a Visual Studio Code terminal.
```

This is also confirmed (and tagged) as being `as designed` by one of VS Code Remote devs in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/1042#issuecomment-515691156):

> This is correct the 'vs code server CLI' is only available from the integrated terminal.

---

So VS Code Remote or even `openvscode-server` make it impossible to automate installs of first- or third-party extensions for this popular Microsoft IDE, unless you run their custom terminal inside their closed-source IDE, which normally entails buying a license for their GUI-based closed-source operating system as well;)